# Can I send a post request to a js file instead of php?

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

First of all I don't want to interact with the server in this transaction.
I'm using the fetch api to send a request but in url I want to pass a js file. Something like this-

```
fetch("includes/handlers/handle.js", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: h,
  body: body
});
```

Also if it's possible can we be getting the POST variables using JS only?

I know this might seem like it doesn't make any sense to do it this way. But I'm trying something and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, as long as the server you requested the file from provides the file.

Comment: What do you mean by “not interact with the server”? What *specifically* are you trying to do? `fetch` fetches. It has to fetch from somewhere.

Comment: "*I'm using the fetch api to send a request*" "*I don't want to interact with the server in this transaction*" Pick one.

Comment: It may be helpful to include a bit of context as to what that "*something*" is that you're trying. Sounds to me like an XY problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a POST request to any URL you like.

You can't avoid interacting with the server when making requests to HTTP URLs. (And only HTTP URLs support POST requests).

It is up to the server to process that request.

You can write server-side code using JavaScript with tools like Node.js or Deno (Node.js being the most common approach).

Typically, when you do so, URLs where POST request bodies will be processed will not have `.js` in the URL - that is normally only used to serve static files to the client.

---

You cannot read the body of a POST request with client-side JS.

Answer (score -2):

It's quite odd, but I do think it's possible.
You should remove any static serving for .js files on your server,
and differentiate between static client side js files & http request handlers.